# javascript filter function - callback function issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, callback

below is javascript code with filter function. when using below code, it works perfectly-

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

but below code gives an empty array. Why?

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter((word) => {
word.length > 6;
});

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Comment: In the first case, you didn't use a curly brace, so it returns the `word.length > 6` expressions output. But in the 2nd case, you've used curly brace so you have to use the return keyword to return `true/false` explicitly.

Comment: So for the 2nd case if you do something like `(word) => { return word.length > 6;}` then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to return the `Boolean` value in function so that it filters accordingly

See-

```
const result = words.filter((word) => {
    return word.length > 6;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use curly brackets in callback you should return something

```
const result = words.filter((word) => {
    return word.length > 6;
});
```

This will work for you

Comment: Can't believe my answer was 10sec slower but same !

Comment: @Sanmeet hehe, I can feel you bro!!